# JSON to Parquet Kinesis Firehose timestamp column

Tags: json, amazon-s3, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using a Kinesis Firehose to write JSON data coming from IoT core into S3.

I have enabled the data format conversion to transform the JSON payload to parquet. For that I have an AWS Glue table scheme, e.g.

```
temperature: float
humidity: float
project: string
timestamp: timestamp
```

My JSON payload looks like this:

```
{
"temperature": 20
"humidity": 60
"project": project
"timestamp": 2023-02-17 16:15:16.486570
}
```

The process works fine and I get my parquet file in S3, but oddly it doesn't have the timestamp column. I've tried multiple timestamp formats, it either gives an error in the process or doesn't give me a timestamp column.

What am I missing? What format should the timestamp be?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work.

```
curr_dt = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
payload = '{
    "timestamp": "' + curr_dt + '", 
    "temperature": ' + str(round(temperature, 2)) + ', 
    "humidity":' + str(round(humidity, 3)) + ', 
    "project_id": "1"
    }'
```

Comment: Hive timestamp format is the following `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`